Powershell replace not working when the string has space in it
I have this line of powershell:
$_.Fields[$field.Name].Value.Replace("abc gcb","simple")

Nothing happens when I this simple replace its not happening. How can replace the string with space into a single word?

Works for me.  "abc gcb".Replace("abc gcb","simple")

We don't post images of code here.

At a guess, you probably expected to change the string in-place. This does not happen. The Replace() method creates a new string object, but does not connect the new object with the old variable. You have to manually assign the result to a variable.
So you probably need something more like this:
$_.Fields[$field.Name].Value = $_.Fields[$field.Name].Value.Replace("abc gcb","simple")


Using an extra variable $FieldName = $field.Name you can access it as $_.Fields.$FieldName.Value.Replace("abc gcb","simple")
Also mentioned in this question: How do I access object properties in a dynamic manner?
